# Probability: Expectation: indicator RV, what is 1-((N-1)/N))^n?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Say there are N coupon types, you collect n coupons, and what's the expected number of types of coupons?

My question is specifically about

$1-(\frac{N-1}{N})^n$, the probability of getting a coupon of type i.

I understand that $\frac{N-1}{N}$ is the probability of picking any type except 1 particular type i. And hence $(\frac{N-1}{N})^n$ is picking types distinct from type i for each of n picks, but I don't really understand what the complement is. Is it picking any type except those N-1 types for every pick, i.e. picking only type i every time?

Comment: The complement of "none" is "at least one".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that $\frac{N−1}N$ is the probability of picking any type except 1 particular type i. And hence $(\frac{N−1}N)^n$ is picking types distinct from type i for each of n picks,

In other words, the probability of picking zero amount of type i.  $\mathsf P(X_i=0)=(\frac{N-1}N)^n$

> ... but I don't really understand what the complement is. Is it picking any type except those N-1 types for every pick, i.e. picking only type i every time?

No, it is not "all" or "every".

The complement of "none" is "at least one".   $\mathsf P(X_i\geq 1 )= 1 - (\frac{N-1}N)^n$